# support repository in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

cannot see the support repository in Android SDK Manager to install constraint layout

[image: image of my SDK]

Comment: Click on `Launch Standalone SDK Manager` or `Switch` for extra customization.

Comment: I did so.But it still doesn't show up.